# AWS Access Keys/ Secret keys AWS SSO users

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sso

I have configured AWS Organizations, SSO as per documentations. I have also created users, Groups, permissions. I can get short time AWS access keys/ Secret keys from SSO start page. But is there any way I can get same as we get for IAM users? Because short time keys valid for some time. I tried to attach IAM policy in permissions sets but could not find it there. So is there anything I am missing? Actually a SSO user can not create permanent AWS keys?

Comment: Max session time is 36h? If this is not enough then probably would have to consider making them normal IAM users.

Comment: I can understand that max time can be 36h, but it would be still pain each time log in and got those keys. If I have automated process, I have to go and update keys every time

Comment: I think this is more a question of 'what are you doing with the keys'. In general, you should not need to copy-paste them. If you're using the aws cli or an SDK, then you should be able to setup a config profile to fetch/refresh the credentials automatically.